# How do you get Jira to look in Pull Request comments for ticket numbers in DVCS integration?

Tags: git, github, jira

We currently have our cloud-hosted Jira instance to sync with Github.  We're using the built-in DVCS plugin.

As far as I can tell, the DVCS plugin looks for a Jira Ticket ID (e.g., `BB-1111`) in a Github Pull Request to tie the PR to a ticket.  It looks in the following locations:

- Every git commit message
- The title of the Pull Request
- Any Github Issues in the Repo

I want to know if there's a way to have the Jira DVCS Plugin look at the Github Pull Request *comments* for the Jira Ticket ID.  This would make it easy for a pull request participant to add the Jira Ticket ID in a comment.

As far as I can tell, this is not currently supported.

Comment: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JSWSERVER-16674

Comment: If anyone comes looking for this, there is an open ticket to do exactly this - head over and vote: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BSERV-4557